# Why does C++ prefer this template method to a method overload?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, overloading

Assuming I had two classes, the first one for writing primitive types (`bool`, `int`, `float`, etc.) and the second one extending the first to also write complex types:

```
struct Writer {
    virtual void Write(int value) = 0;
};

struct ComplexWriter : public Writer {
    template <typename TValue> void Write(const TValue &value) {
        boost::any any(value);
        Write(any);
    }
    //virtual void Write(int value) = 0; // see question below
    virtual void Write(const boost::any &any) = 0;
};
```

The idea is that if someone calls `myWriter.Write(someIntValue);`, the int overload will receive priority over the templated method.

Instead, my compiler (Visual C++ 11.0 RC) always picks the template method. The following code snippet, for example, will print `Wrote any` to the console:

```
struct ComplexWriterImpl : public ComplexWriter {
    virtual void Write(int value) { std::cout << "Wrote an int"; }
    virtual void Write(const boost::any &any) { std::cout << "Wrote any"; }
};

void TestWriter(ComplexWriter &writer) {
    int x = 0;
    writer.Write(x);
}

int main() {
    ComplexWriterImpl writer;
    TestWriter(writer);
}
```

The behavior suddenly changes when I declare the `Write(int)` method in the `ComplexWriter` class as well (see commented out line in the first snippet). It then prints `Wrote an int` to the console.

Is this how my compiler ought to behave? Does the C++ standard explicitly say that only overloads defined in the same class (and not a base class) shall be prioritized over a templated method?

Comment: I don't see where you overload a method taking int with one templated. You have two unrelated classes, `Writer` with a method taking `int` and `ComplexWriter` with a templated method (and a method taking `boost::any const&`). In your test code you use `ComplexWriter`, so of course it will call a member of `ComplexWriter`. If you really expected it to call a member of the completely unrelated class `Writer`, can you explain why (and how) it should do that?

Comment: You mention that `ComplexWriter` extends `Writer`, but in the code you listed it does not inherit from `Writer`.  Is this the correct setup?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, ComplexWriter was supposed to derive from Writer. I updated the question accordingly. The outcome is still the same (though of course forgetting to specify that base class connects to the core of my question. outch.).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that at the point you're calling `writer.Write(x)` the compiler sees a `ComplexWriter` not a `ComplexWriterImpl`, so it is only aware of the functions defined in `ComplexWriter` - the template function and the `boost::any` function.

`ComplexWriter` does not contain any virtual functions that accept an `int`, so it has no way to call through to the int overload defined in `ComplexWriterImpl`

When you add in the virtual overload to the `ComplexWriter` class, then the compiler becomes aware that there is an integer overload in the `ComplexWriter` class and therefore calls through to it's implementation in `ComplexWriterImpl`

EDIT: Now that you've edited in the inheritance between ComplexWriter & Writer, I've got a more complete explanation for you:

When you create a subclass and define a function in it then all of the functions of that name in the base class will be hidden, regardless of their argument types.

You can get around this with the using keyword I believe:

```
struct ComplexWriter : public Writer {
    template <typename TValue> void Write(const TValue &value) {
        boost::any any(value);
        Write(any);
    }
    using Writer::Write;
    virtual void Write(const boost::any &any) = 0;
};
```

For more details see this FAQ entry: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9

EDIT 2: Just to confirm that this does indeed solve your problem: http://ideone.com/LRb5a

Comment: Yep, I forgot to specify the base class in my snippet. ComplexWriter does inherit from Writer, but the behavior I'm observing is as I explained it, even with the base class correctly specified.

Comment: @Cygon Yeah, noticed that.  I'm just trying to come up with an explanation/edit just now.  Though I may end up deleting this answer if I fail!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply in any case! Forgetting to specify the base class was really a silly mistake to make as it skewed the entire question :)

Comment: Nice! I've been writing C++ for several years and never encountered this type of using statement before. It produces the desired outcome in my actual on GCC and MSVC even with multiple overloads.

Answer (score 2):

When you access the object via the `ComplexWriter` "interface", the compiler will try to resolve the function call to `Write(int)` using the definitions in that class.  If it does not able to do so, it will consider base classes.

In this case, you have two candidates: `Write(any)` and the templated version.  Since there is no explicit `Write(int)` available at this point, it will have to choose between these two options.  `Write(any)` requires an implicit conversion, while the templated version does not, so the templated version is called (which in turn calls `Write(any)`).

To make the `Write(int)` from `Writer` available, import the `Writer::Write` functions:

```
class ComplexWriter : public Writer
{
  using Writer::Write;
  // rest is as before
};
```